# Conventional way of representing uncertainty

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, multilabel-classification, uncertainty

I am calculating metrics such as F1 score, Recall, Precision and Accuracy in multilabel classification setting. With random initiliazed weights the softmax output (i.e. prediction) might look like this with a batch size of 8 (I am using `pytorch`):

```
import torch
logits = torch.tensor([[ 0.0334, -0.0896, -0.0832, -0.0682, -0.0707],
                       [ 0.0322, -0.0897, -0.0829, -0.0683, -0.0708],
                       [ 0.0324, -0.0894, -0.0829, -0.0682, -0.0705],
                       [ 0.0322, -0.0897, -0.0828, -0.0683, -0.0708],
                       [ 0.0333, -0.0895, -0.0832, -0.0682, -0.0708],
                       [ 0.0341, -0.0871, -0.0829, -0.0681, -0.0650],
                       [ 0.0329, -0.0894, -0.0832, -0.0678, -0.0716],
                       [ 0.0324, -0.0897, -0.0830, -0.0683, -0.0708]])

y_pred_label1 = logits[:,:3].softmax(1)
y_pred_label2 = logits[:,3:].softmax(1)
```

With the correct labels (one-hot encoded):

```
y_true = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], # this row is correctly predicted
                       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

I can calculate the metrics by taking the argmax (index of max value) of the corresponding row dimension:

```
from torchmetrics.functional import f1_score

y_pred_label1 = y_pred_label1.argmax(1) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
y_pred_label2 = y_pred_label2.argmax(1) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

y_true_label1 = y_true[:,:3].argmax(1) #  [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_true_label2 = y_true[:, 3:].argmax(1) # [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

f1_label1 = f1_score(y_pred_label1, y_true_label1, num_classes=3)
f1_label2 = f1_score(y_pred_label2, y_true_label2, num_classes=2)

f1_label1, f1_label2
```

Output:

```
(tensor(0.1250), tensor(0.5000))
```

The first prediction happens to be correct while the rest are wrong. However, none of the predictive probabilities in label1 are above 0.5, which means that the model is generally uncertain about the predictions. What is the common way of encoding this uncertainty? I would like the f1 score to be 0.0 because none of the predictive probabilities are above a 0.5 threshold.

An idea I had was set these values manually by using some "dummy label" outside the target range, but there might be a better way to think about this.

Since this type of operation seems to lack documentation in both the `sklearn` and `torchmetrics` library, I am not sure if this is common practice?

Comment: It looks like you want to evaluate the probability values, not discrete classes. Vanderbilt’s Frank Harrell has written about this many times. https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/ https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's not really an answer to the question asked but I think that there's a serious problem in your approach:

- You're applying softmax on the vector of predictions across labels
- You also pick the argmax for both the predicted and true labels.

These two things make sense for the *multiclass* setting, but they are not consistent with the multi-label setting: in the multi-label setting, the labels and their probabilities are supposed to be independent of each other. Softmax results in a vector of probabilities which sum to 1, representing the chances of each class to be *the unique correct one* (this is correct for the multiclass setting only).

The argmax on a multi-label true vector doesn't make any sense either: if the instance has more than one label (as intended), I'm not sure what argmax does (pick one of the labels randomly?), but it certainly returns a single label, ignoring any other one.

The evaluation of multi-label classification must be done for every label independently, i.e. you should obtain a value of precision, recall, f1-score *for every label*. Then you can calculate macro- or micro- precision, recall, f1-score across the labels.

Comment: You're right, I mixed up multiclass with multilabel when trying to simplify my problem. The first three columns are associated with one label and the last two columns are associated with another (binary) label. So what I am doing is slicing the array and doing a softmax over the columns that pertain to the individual labels and finally combining them to compare with the target. I will edit my post and I hope this makes things a bit more clear :)

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure that I understand everything, but I suspect that there is something wrong in the design of the system. As far as I understand the probabilities are calculated for the two labels together, so they are not independent and the system is always going to predict a single 1 in the OHT representation. Also I don't see the point of one-hot-encoding the labels.I'd suggest you try to implement the system to predict a single label and check if it predictions are the same as the current system for this label (I doubt that it would be the same).

Comment: I think that the low probabilities and uncertainty issues that you obtain are partly a consequence of this design issue, because the probabilities are split among more values than they should be. As far as I understand you should have the probs of the 3 classes 0, 1, 2 sum to 1 for the first label, and the probs of the 2 classes 0 and 1 sum to 1 for the 2nd label.